# Powershell Skip Folder using Get-ChildItem

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

Part of a PowerShell script I am running, I want it to completely ignore a specific folder or path.

I've tried to use the `-notmatch` and also `-notlike` operator. But it seems it will still go through every file in that folder. While it won't process items in that folder, so I get the desired result, there's still hundreds of thousands of files in that folder and can take a long time just to run through the script. I just want it to completely bypass that folder.

Here is the part of the script that I have:

```
$allfiles = Get-ChildItem -path $BaseDirectory -Force -File -Recurse | ? { $_.FullName -notmatch 'DATA\SHARED\GAMES\STEAM\SteamLibrary' } | select-object Name,FullName,Length
```

I have also tried:

```
Where { $_.FullName -notlike '*\DATA\SHARED\GAMES\STEAM\SteamLibrary\*' }
```

Is there a better way to have it just skip that folder altogether, preferably using the relative path? Or even just folder name `SteamLibrary`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all the directories exceept SteamLibrary & *then* get the files in each:

```
$allfiles = Get-ChildItem $BaseDirectory -Dir -Force -Recurse |
    ? Name -notLike 'SteamLibrary' |
        Get-ChildItem -File -Force |
            select-object Name,FullName,Length
```

---

### Options for excluding multiple items

If we wanted to exclude more than one folder, we could use:

```
gci -dir -recurse |
   ? ( Name -notLike 'SteamLibrary' ) -and ( Name -notLike 'PCBACKUP' ) | ...
```

But with just two values, it's already getting cumbersome. The `-match/notMatch` operators use regular expressions rather than simple wildcards, so to exclue multiple values, we can use the regex `or` operaotor: `|`:

```
gci -dir -recurse |
   ? ( Name -notMatch 'SteamLibrary|PCBACKUP' ) | ...
```

and this could be expanded to 3, 4, or 5 values & still be managable. Also, the comparison string can be defined in a variable earlier in the code:

```
$Exclude = 'Iowa|Maine|Ohio|Utah'
gci -dir -recurse |
   ? ( Name -notMatch $Exclude ) | ...
```

For larger collections of exclusion values, the best approach is probably placing the exclusion values in a string array and using the `-notIn` operator:

```
$Exclude = @'
Iowa
Maine
Ohio
Utah
Illinois
Indiana
Missouri
Mississippi
'@ -split "`n"
gci -dir -recurse |
   ? ( Name -notMatch $Exclude ) | ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Very much appreciated.

Comment: One quick question (hopefully). How would I go about excluding multiple folders? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just meant how to manage multiple `-notlike` or `-notmatch` entries. So if I wanted to exclude `SteamLibrary` as well as `PCBACKUP` ...
But it seems I can use just use the `-and` operator so `$_.FullName -notmatch 'SteamLibrary' -and $_.FullName -notmatch 'PCBACKUP'`

Comment: As with so many tinings in **PowerShell**, there are several ways to accomplish this. First, a quick correction to your expresssions above: `FullName` vs. `Name`. `FullName` is the fully qualified path of a directory or file, whereas name is just the item name. For our comparisons, `Name` is the better choice. As for filtering against multiple exclusion values, I'm going to edit my answer for fromatting & easier reading.

Comment: Thanks again. This may be a mundane question, and I am really trying to learn here, and thanks so much for your input. But when I use the @' with the array of names in PowerShell ISE it's like it doesn't close out the command properly and shows the rest of data with squiggly lines underneath like this: https://imgur.com/a/ZegS8a3 This tells me there is likely an error and won't execute properly. Also if I want to include a partial path (i.e. \DATA\PCBACKUP) wouldn't FullName be better?

Comment: The error is due to the `here-string` definition being [indented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295135/powershell-indent-here-string). And if you only un-indent the closing `'@`your comparisions wouold fail because the resulting strings would have leading spaces. If you want to check partial or complete paths instead of just the name, then yes, you would use `FullName`. That just wasn't the case in the original examples.